# Dynamic column width in table with advanced css selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-tables

I once found a small piece of CSS code here that let me set the width of a column in a table based on the amount of columns in the table. Sadly my search-fu is not able to give me an answer. So I decided to ask directly.

I remember the CSS code went something like this:

```
table tr td:nth-of-type(1) ~ table tr td:nth-of-type(3) {
   width: 33%;
};
```

Where the above code would make every column in a table with 3 columns be 33% at width.

```
table tr td:nth-of-type(1) ~ table tr td:nth-of-type(4) {
   width: 25%;
};
```

And with this every column in a table with 4 columns be 25% width.

Comment: I think you're looking for "quantity queries"

Comment: What exactly is your question? Seems you have a solution already. What do you need help with?

Comment: You can probably get rid of `table tr` in those css selectors. `td` elements always children of `tr`, and `tr` are always children of `table`.